# Ошибка при работе с датой в Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Используя Laravel, пытаюсь вывести во `view` для создания **sitemap.xml**:

```
{{ $content->updated_at->tz('UTC')->toAtomString() }}
```

но выдает:

> Call to a member function tz() on null

---

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

решил вот так

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($content->updated_at)->tz('UTC')->toAtomString() }}
```

Comment: Не совсем корректное решение. В данном случае если вы передаете в `parse` значение `null`, то `Carbon` вернет вам текущее значение времени. Вас это устроит?